# Drawing rectangle on uEye Camera c#

Tags: c#, camera, drawing, picturebox

I am creating a application which displays a live view from a uEye camera in c# using visual studio. I have displayed the camera view in a picturebox.

I am wanting the user to type in a width and height they would like, once they have done this it will display this rectangle on the picturebox which has the camera view in.

I am using the following code...

```
Pen p = new Pen(Color.Red, 1);
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(10, 10, Convert.ToInt32(width), Convert.ToInt32(height));
DisplayWindow.CreateGraphics().DrawRectangle(p, rect);
```

This draws the rectangle on the picture box but for only a second, then it disappears. Anyone know why this is?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement something like this; what happens is async drawing, resulting in strange behaviour.

```
DisplayWindow.Paint += (o, e) =>
{
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(p, rect);
};

//To force redraw, just call
DisplayWindow.Invalidate();
```

Comment: This just displays a very large box with a x in it, then it disappears again after a second.

Comment: Thats because something went wrong when drawing, may be a null exception somewhere.